# Simplifying casting in my C/C++ qsort char** comparator function

Tags: c++, casting

I have a comparator function I use with `qsort` to sort an array of `char*` (i.e., `char**`), which compiles with current versions of Clang and GCC without giving errors or warnings:

```
static int
comparator(const void* a, const void* b)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    auto a_recast = const_cast<void *>(a);
    auto b_recast = const_cast<void *>(b);
    auto a_rerecast = reinterpret_cast<char **>(a_recast);
    auto b_rerecast = reinterpret_cast<char **>(b_recast);
    auto a_rererecast = const_cast<const char **>(a_rerecast);
    auto b_rererecast = const_cast<const char **>(b_rerecast);
    return std::strcmp(*a_rererecast, *b_rererecast);
#else
    return strcmp(*(const char**) a, *(const char**) b);
#endif
}
```

It compiles conditionally, that is, depending on whether a C or C++ compiler is used, one or the other block of code is compiled.

I offer both blocks, because this is part of a program that can be compiled alone in C, or in a larger suite of tools compiled with a C++ toolkit.

My question is about the work I had to do to in the C++ block, where I strip `const`, recast to `char **`, and reapply `const`.

Is there a simpler or cleaner way to do this C++-style casting, which generates the correct end results and does not result in warnings about C-style casting?

Clang, in particular, is chatty with warnings about old C-style casts, and I like my build logs to be clean, where fixes are realistic.

I also like the code to be clear and easy to and maintain. I'd also like to `inline` this code, which would probably be easier for the compiler if the comparator function is smaller.

If I'm doing the correct work, that's fine, but if there are better ways, I'd be interested to learn them. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What's wrong with C-style-casts? And why would you use conditional compilation instead of including `<string.h>`? As an aside, you would use `std::sort()` in C++ because it's far more efficient and type-safe.

Comment: This is great criticism! Please give me all you've got, I want to learn.

Comment: Is there a good reason you need to write bilingual (C and C++) *code*?  Usually, `#ifdef __cplusplus` is something you'd use in a *header* so that you can link C code with C++ code.  I'd recommend you write this as C, and declare it with C linkage (i.e. `extern "C"`, when `__cplusplus` is defined).

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
int comparator(const void* a, const void* b)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    auto a_recast = static_cast<const char* const *>(a);
    auto b_recast = static_cast<const char* const *>(b);
    return std::strcmp(*a_recast, *b_recast);
#else
    return strcmp(*(const char* const *) a, *(const char* const *) b);
#endif
}
```

To elaborate, the reason that you had to go through the convoluted series of dangerous casts is that you actually were stripping constness. 
`const void*` means a promise not to change whatever the `void` turns out to be. That is, the thing pointed at by the rightmost star is const. `const char **` on the other hand means a promise not to change the individual characters, but doesn't guarantee that you won't change the direct pointers to those characters. However, it's the pointers to those characters that are pointed at by the rightmost star. Intuitively perhaps, think of `char *` as being in a unit by itself a c_string, and your a and b are arrays of constant c_strings.

The reason that clang warns about c style casts is precisely that they let you apply such a crazy list of operations and changing constnesses without necessarily realizing what is happening.

As an aside, as far as the compiler is concerned, it is actually only necessary to enforce constness on the pointer. That is, you could also compile with `static_cast<char * const *>`. I put the additional const in because when your conceptual c_string is constant, you conceptually don't want to be changing any of the characters. (And you probably want the compiler to alert you if anything tries to do that.)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use this in C and C++ programs, there's a mechanism to save you writing two versions.  Write the C code in the normal way, but with *external* linkage:

```
#include <string.h>

int char_string_comparator(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char *const *const sa = a;
    const char *const *const sb = b;
    return strcmp(*sa, *sb);
}
```

(Note that I've avoided casts, by assigning to compatible temporary variables - any optimizing compiler should produce the same code as for your version, but there's more checking performed in this one).

Compile it to an object file, and write a header so that you can link it with either C or C++ programs:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int char_string_comparator(const void* a, const void* b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

All that said, I have never needed `std::qsort()` when writing C++.  Instead, use `std::sort()` (from `<algorithm>`) when something needs sorting.  Because it's a template, it's correctly type-safe, and you can't use a comparator that doesn't match the data type.

Comment: `const char *const *const sa = a;` holy cow! It looks like inception :-o

Comment: Okay @t3chb0t, the very last `const` in that type is pretty unnecessary, given we can see that we never assign to `sa` after it's initialized.  But my fingers were on a roll by then...  I suppose if I wanted to make it musical, then I could go for `char const*const*const`!

Comment: I have no idea what this is for but it's pretty scarry. Can't you just write `char const^3` - just kidding ;-)

Comment: No @t3chb0t. That XORs const and 3! ;-)

Comment: @Josiah oh, I actaully meant `^` as mathematical _power_.

Comment: `char const³`, obviously.